# Segmentation Fault Issue possible caused by Redefinition Error (1 File)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, segmentation-fault, gdb, g++

first post so give me some slack.

I've been having issues with running a neural network using 
`g++-8.2.0 -std=c++2a proj1.cpp a`

When run using Visual Studio, the program compiled and ran flawlessly, and executed according to desired logic. When run using g++; however, the code runs into the following segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000409100 in std::string::_M_data() const ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.4.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000409100 in std::string::_M_data() const ()
#1  0x0000000000409170 in std::string::_M_rep() const ()
#2  0x0000000000406c4c in std::string::length() const ()
#3  0x0000000000404df6 in main ()
```

After receiving this error, I added some try-catch blocks and tried to recompile with -g flag. When compiled with -g, the program would not compile and returned several multiple definition errors; however, this is the only file used, and all includes are in std library. The full error reported is:

```
a:(.bss+0x1c0): multiple definition of `gMap'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:(.bss+0x60): first defined here
a:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/lib/../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
a: In function `main':
(.text+0x218c): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:621: first defined here
a: In function `letterPicker(Network*)':
(.text+0xe01): multiple definition of `letterPicker(Network*)'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:345: first defined here
a: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/opt/gcc8.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
a: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/lib/../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
a: In function `T()':
(.text+0xe8): multiple definition of `T()'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:19: first defined here
a: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/lib/../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
a: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/lib/../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
a: In function `gP(float)':
(.text+0x114d): multiple definition of `gP(float)'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:414: first defined here
a: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/lib/../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
a: In function `valueOf(int)':
(.text+0xf6): multiple definition of `valueOf(int)'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:25: first defined here
a: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x18): multiple definition of `DEBUG'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:19: first defined here
a:(.bss+0x160): multiple definition of `solution'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:19: first defined here
a: In function `g(float)':
(.text+0xfb9): multiple definition of `g(float)'
/tmp/cc0u5Onx.o:/home/ugrads/d/dhlaurel/ms_windows/cpsc_redirected/cmpSci/csce420/proj/proj1.cpp:374: first defined here
/opt/gcc8.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
a:(.data+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in a(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure where the issue in question is occurring, but after adding some blocks to my main file, it was unable to even reach line 1, so I've decided to include my #includes as well as my main file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>


int main()
{
    int numLayers = 4;  //at least 2
    int hiddLayerSize = 16;
    int inputSize;
    int outputSize;
    std::cout << "ERROR BLOCK 1";
    std::vector<std::vector< std::string >  > letters;
    try{
        letters = bdfReader("ie9x14u.bdf");
    }catch (std::exception const &e){
        std::cout << "FILE READ ERROR\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> starLetters;
    std::cout << "ERROR BLOCK 2";

    std::vector<std::string> letterInput = sampleInp(letters);
    std::vector<std::string> letterOutput = std::vector<std::string>(26, "00000000000000000000000000");

    /* This was where I thought the problem might be occurring since it mentioned string errors, but after commenting it out, nothing happened

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letterOutput[i][i] = '1';
    }
    */





    inputSize = letterInput[0].length();
    outputSize = letterOutput[0].length();



    Network* letterNet = new Network(majorityInput, majorityOutput, numLayers, hiddLayerSize, inputSize, outputSize);


    std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string> > majExamp = std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string> >(majorityInput, majorityOutput);

    std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string> > letterExamp = std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string> >(letterInput, letterOutput);

    letterNet = backPropLearn(letterExamp, letterNet);

    std::cout << weightsPrinter(letterNet);
    std::cout << std::to_string(networkAcc(letterExamp, letterNet)) + "* 100%\n";
    std::cout << "\n all done";


    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As mentioned before, the program compiles and executes flawlessly in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Note: `Try`/`catch` only handles C++ exceptions. Lower level stuff like operating system exceptions, signals, and other program-killers are not catchable.

Comment: This may actually be my problem. I tried checking the length of the string returned instead of solely relying on the try/catch, and I seem to be making progress. Thanks a lot! Will update with results.

Comment: I assume that `proj1.cpp` is the source-file you show? But what is `a` that you also provide when building?

Comment: And are you really building the exact same files when you get the multiple definition errors? The `-g` flag should not by itself cause such errors, you should have those errors with or without the `-g` flag (or not at all).

Comment: Looks like you left out a bunch of functions you're calling. We love minimal, but we require Complete and Verifiable. Read [mcve] for more details. The true beauty of the MCVE is that while building one you very often find the problem and solution yourself. I strongly recommend backing up your code and making one before asking a question here. All you added to the given command line was the -g?

Comment: Other useful g++-isms is to add `-Wall -Wextra` to the command line. This tells the compiler to report on extra anomalies in the code that do not block compilation but could result in an unstable program.

Comment: Use `cerr` when looking for a crash—any text left in `cout`’s buffer will not be displayed.